# In Emacs how to prevent the same buffer from showing up in different windows in the same frame?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm not sure how to comprehensively accomplish this.

Currently I build my own bzr Emacs on Windows, so I can see that `display-buffer' now takes a SPECIFIERS option, which could be interesting, but I couldn't find concrete examples of how to use it.

But this problem really has to be solved before display-buffer is called.

For example a Help window previously was visiting Buffer-A, but I've visited Buffer-A in another window while reading the help.  Now when I quit the Help window, Buffer-A appears there as well.  I want some other useful buffer to appear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some experimental code that appears to work [here](https://github.com/lewang/unique-window-buffers).

I emphasize experimental.  This could melt your Emacs.

I'd appreciate it if you could contact me on github or here to let me know your experiences with this.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs 24 is not yet released. They have changed the buffer-display/window behavior and Lisp interfaces several times over the release's development period. The current status of the release is *pretest*, so development is supposedly stopped, except for bug fixes.

However, ongoing `emacs-devel@gnu.org` discussions show that things are still in flux wrt buffer display and windows.

Your best bet is to check the latest doc and code (which might not correspond exactly, at this point).